# Resolving long URL from Shorturl

Tags: php, url

I am trying to resolve long URLs from Twitter's short URLs, My function is,

```
public function expand_short_url($url = '')
{
    if($url != '')
    {
        $headers = get_headers($url);
        $headers = array_reverse($headers);
        foreach($headers as $header) {
            if (strpos($header, 'Location: ') === 0) {
                $url = str_replace('Location: ', '', $header);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return $url;
}
```

This function has a huge performance impact. I benchmark the JSON response,

```
Without resolving  : 1.73 seconds
With URL resolving : 1.2 min
```

Any other suggestion, or faster way to resolve short urls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, at first take a look at `The media entity` section in [Tweet Entities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) (you can get the expanded url with) if it helps. Also, by default [get_headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) uses a `GET` (is slower than HEAD) request to fetch the headers. If you want to send a HEAD request instead, you can do so using a stream context:

```
stream_context_set_default(
    array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => 'HEAD'
        )
    )
);
$headers = get_headers('http://example.com');
```

[Curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) is even faster but I recommend you to read [Resolve Short URLs To Their Destination URL with PHP (such as T.co, bit.ly & tinyurl.com)](http://www.internoetics.com/2012/11/12/resolve-short-urls-to-their-destination-url-php-api/), it could be very helpful, the title describes it clearly and i think this is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Curl option turned out to be much faster. Thanks.

Comment: That article and its page is gone:
http://web.archive.org/web/20160401102504/http://www.internoetics.com/2012/11/12/resolve-short-urls-to-their-destination-url-php-api/